# Divides proof $a \mid b$ and $a \mid(2b - c)$ then $a \mid c$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Can you please confirm my logic for this question is correct.

$a \mid b$ and $a \mid(2b - c),\;$  then $\;a \mid c$

As $a$ divides $b$,  $b = ax$ for some integer $x$.

$$2b - c = 2(ax) - c$$

$c = a(2x)$ as $2x$ is an integer.

Hence $a \mid c$

Thanks for the help

Comment: You haven't used $a\mid(2b-c)$ anywhere.

Comment: I don't understand how you conclude that $c=a(2x)$, could you explain your reasoning for that?

Comment: Sorry.

So my logic was as we know a | 2b - c then 2b - c = 2(ax) - c

Comment: If $a | 2b-c$, then $ay=2b-c$ for some integer $y$. Or, if you want to substitute $b=ax$, then we can say $a | 2ax-c$.  This still does not imply $c=2ax$.

Answer (score 2):

Your claim that $c = a(2x)$ holds only if $c = 2a$.

Instead use the fact there is a second integer $y$ with $ay = 2b - c$.

Then $c = 2b - ay = 2(ax) - ay = a(2x - y)$, meaning $a | c$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you get the $c=a(2x)$ lines from. Alternatively, a little easier: If $a\vert b$ and $a\vert 2b-c$, then $a$ divides any linear combination of these two. Therefore, $a\vert 2b-1\cdot(2b-c)\implies a\vert c$.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$b=na$$ and $$2b-c=ma$$ thus we have $$2na-c=ma$$ and we get
$$a(2n-m)=c$$ this means $$a|c$$

Comment: -1 "Can you please confirm my logic for this question is correct."

Comment: no your answer is not correct

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Whilst you have provided a correct method, it does not specifically address the OP's question as to what is wrong with his method.

Comment: you haven't used that $$2b-c=am$$ with some integer $m$

Comment: I's worth mentioning that this is an example of the Euclidean algorithm

Answer (score 0):

By hypothesis, $ax=b$ for some integer $x$ and $ay=2b-c$ for some integer $y$.  Hence, $ay=2(ax)-c$ for some integers $x$ and $y$.  Simplifying, we get that $a(2x-y)=c$, which implies that $a$ divides $c$.